# Execute number of commands from a text file

Tags: bash, sh

I have the below script which need to get the output for the command where I am not able to get the output for the commands which has space Ex: "cat test.txt"

Need to execute 1000 commands for a server. Need to apply a script as below and expected the output as below.

****Script: **

```
#!/bin/sh
a=`whoami`"@"`hostname`":~$"

IFS=''
while read line; do

command=$line
b=line
for command in $line
do
        echo $a "$command"
        `$command`
        echo $a
done
done < test.txt
```

```
**Out I m getting as below:**

rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$ ls
forloop.sh  scripts.sh  test.sh  test.txt
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$ pwd
/tmp
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$ date
Fri Dec 16 19:29:35 IST 2022
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$ cat test.txt
forloop.sh: 12: cat test.txt: not found
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$

**Expected output**

rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$ ls
forloop.sh  scripts.sh  test.sh  test.txt
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$ pwd
/tmp
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$ date
Fri Dec 16 19:29:35 IST 2022
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$ cat test.txt
**Here it should open the contents of the file**
rootjey@C-2PZ1DK3:~$
```

for the single commands, it is getting executed but for the commands which has spaces in between is not able to retrieve.

Please help with a solution or hint.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `bash` when you use `sh`?

Comment: You may consider reading [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: If the commands are in a file, why don't you execute that file ?

Comment: @Cyrus: Have tried with both, didn't get the expected output.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin: Didn't get the exact information brother

Comment: @Itération122442: I need it with the prompt, the file execution will provide me only the output.

Comment: @JeyaganeshS You can use `set -x` in bash to prompt what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, you need to **remove** that IFS definition.

You should have **only one logical command** per input line, i.e.

```
du -s * 2>>/dev/null | awk 'BEGIN{ sum=0 ;}{ sum=sum+$1 ; }END{ print sum ; }'
```

Also, you can define **any string** as divider.

You forgot to **escape the dollar sign** in your definition of "**a**".

You didn't need the "**for**" loop.  It really serves no purpose.

The proposed revision of the script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=`whoami`"@"`hostname`":~\$"

while read command
do
    echo -e "\n###############################################################\n$a $command"
    eval ${command}
done < test.txt
echo $a
```

Given the number of commands to be executed (*hopefully not inter-dependant*), you might want to consider adding a **count-down** to get a sense of how many lines remaining for completion of the batch sequence.

If inter-dependant, you might want to consider adding a test before each command execution, something like

```
if [ -f ${COMMAND_NUMBER}.success ]
```

in order to skip that command on a second or third run of the same script with the same input file, **but to abandon if $? is not equal to zero.**

Comment: Hi Eric
It  worked , I understood the code now. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  When the solution meets the needs of the original problem, you should indicate that by clicking on the checkmark near the top-left of the Answer.